# Message Sent To Deallocated Instance on UIButton inside iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, icarousel

I have implemented iCarousel (https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) into my Xcode project and now have a scrolling carousel of views. Inside each view I have a UIButton, which I have added a UILongPressGestureRecogniser to, like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[lpgr setMinimumPressDuration:1.5];
[lpgr addTarget:self action:@selector(testAction)];
[self.demoButton addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

However, when I tap for 1.5 seconds, the following error is displayed in the console:

**2014-07-01 09:50:08.002 ExampleApp[3117:892602]**  -[ExampleVC testAction]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15cd7bd20
(lldb)*

I haven't seen any section of the code which is releasing the views, so very confused. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Should the selector be `testAction:` instead of `testAction` ?

Comment: Nope, it isn't necessary

Comment: Check if your button and also the view where the button is on is still actually in memory and has not been deallocated yet.

Comment: I think you should assign the `Gesture` in `- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` method, instead of anywhere else. Just try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there can be a problem like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[lpgr setMinimumPressDuration:1.5];
[lpgr addTarget:self action:@selector(testAction)];
[self.demoButton addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

You forgot to release lpgr after these lines.

```
[lpgr release];
```

And if you miss this line, and demo button is released by iCarussel because of memory optimization, your gestureRecognizer won't be released and will send a message to the deallocated demoButton.

And use the LongPress like this:

```
[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
```

and handle:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture

    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
    }
}
```

and don't forget to implement `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

Update:

> Inside each view I have a UIButton

You have a button inside each view, but about your code I see that you have a class variable demobutton. So when you initialize a view add your demo button like this:

```
    UIView* yourView ...

    UIButton* demoButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [yourView addSubview:demoButton];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [lpgr setMinimumPressDuration:1.5];
    [lpgr addTarget:self action:@selector(testAction:)];
    [demoButton addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    [demoButton release];
    [lpgr release];
```

Comment: Is this applicable on an ARC environment as well?

Comment: In ARC you don't have to release. ( and of corse you can't because Xcode don't let you )

Comment: Thanks for this, although the crash still occurs even after making these changes, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you coding with ARC or Non-Arc?  Enable NSZombie can be useful to detect your problem. After enabling update your question with the new error line. Or post your whole code,and maybe I can help more.

Comment: Can you pls show me your - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view  method